# C# Poll multiple devices to determine IP type: Static or DHCP

Tags: c#, networking, dhcp

Would like to know the c# code to actually retrieve the IP type: Static or DHCP based on a list of devices I will enter.

Output to be viewed:

```
Device name:  IP Address:   MAC Address:         Type:  
Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller NULL    00:00:F3:44:C6:00   DHCP
Generic Marvell Yukon 88E8056 based Ethernet Controller 192.168.1.102   00:00:F3:44:D0:00   DHCP
```

```
            ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        txtLaunch.Text = ("Name\tIP Address\tMAC Address\tType" +"\r\n");

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            object o = objMO.GetPropertyValue("IPAddress");
            object m = objMO.GetPropertyValue("MACAddress");

            if (o != null || m != null)
            {
                builder.Append(objMO["Description"].ToString());
                builder.Append("\t");
                    if (o != null)
                       builder.Append(((string[])(objMO["IPAddress"]))[0].ToString());
                    else
                       builder.Append("NULL");
                builder.Append("\t");
                builder.Append(m.ToString());
                builder.Append("\t");
                builder.Append(Convert.ToBoolean(objMO["DHCPEnabled"]) ? "DHCP" : "Static");
                builder.Append("\r\n");
            }

            txtLaunch.Text = txtLaunch.Text + (builder.ToString());
```

This gave me 90% of what I am looking to achieve - the code worked out well.  The next portion is to specify a device on the network to obtain the information remotely.  I noticed the one comment below that stated this was impossible without WMI. This is certainly much closer than I was. I'm convinced this can be accomplished. I'm open to recommendations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: sorry, some properties can be NULL on some adapters. Fixed below**

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass(
                        "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

Console.WriteLine("Name\tIP Address\tMAC Address\tType");

foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  builder.Append(objMO["Description"].ToString());
  builder.Append("\t");
  object o = objMO.GetPropertyValue("IPAddress");

  if (o != null)
      builder.Append(((string[])(objMO["IPAddress"]))[0].ToString());
  else
      builder.Append("NULL");

  builder.Append("\t");

  object m = objMO.GetPropertyValue("MACAddress");

  if (m != null)
      builder.Append(m.ToString());
  else
      builder.Append("NULL");

  builder.Append("\t");
  builder.Append(Convert.ToBoolean(objMO["DHCPEnabled"]) ? "DHCP" : "Static");
  Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do you have a recommendation as to how to poll additional devices on a network?

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/internetweb/article.php/c6023/
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you're trying to do this for remote hosts, you won't be able to do this.  You'll need access to the DHCP server and its logging to identify this information.</strike>

Edit: of course, through WMI works if that's available.